# Tutorial for getting nearest bars using Android Places API?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I would like to use the Places API to find the geocoordinates of the nearest bars using Google Places. I'd like to store around 15 of the nearest geocoordinates in an ArrayList. Does there exist a simple demo of how to accomplish this? More generally, I would like to see a quick and dirty concrete working example of how to use the Places API to query for locations.

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you. https://developers.google.com/places/#PlaceSearches you can get all nearest locations using the goole api.